# VB.NET Array with Strings

Tags: vb.net

how do i copy 2 to 3 elements from Array 1 to another Array

**Pets**

dog 1
dog 2
dog 6
cat 1
cat 2

```
Dim pet as String = "dog"
```

i want to copy the array elements form Array 1 to Array 2 only the elements with "dog" LIKE using the string named pet

**Dog**

dog 1
dog 2
dog 6

Comment: I want a ruby encrusted pony.

Comment: So… `array1.Where(Function(x) x.Contains("dog")).ToArray()`?

Comment: Not a real question but people have viewed it 14687 times... Haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what @rynah's example essentially does under the hood:

```
    Dim array1() As String = {"dog 1", "dog 2", "dog 6", "cat 1", "cat2"}

    Dim tmpList As New List(Of String)
    For Each value As String In array1
        If value.Contains("dog") Then
            tmpList.Add(value)
        End If
    Next

    Dim array2() As String = tmpList.ToArray
    For Each value As String In array2
        Debug.Print(value)
    Next
```